# Casting a Class<? extends SomeClass> to SomeClass?

Tags: java, eclipse, casting

I've been making a weighted, random enemy spawn system, which works fine, except that changed the weights doesn't.

I've been trying to cast a Class to just the pure Enemy class, which is what breaks the system, or at least Eclipse IDE says that.

The code that breaks is this:

```
enemy.cast(Enemy.class).getId()[0]
```

The .getId() is part of the Enemy class, thus the need for this in the first place.

The output from Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Class to com.frenchfry.enemies.EnemyBasic
at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for the any help in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
Enumeration<Class<? extends Enemy>> e = currentWeights.keys();
        enemyWeights.clear();
        currentWeights.clear();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()){
            Class<? extends Enemy> en = e.nextElement();
            Enemy enemy = en.cast(Enemy.class);
            int weight = currentWeights.get(enemy);
            double weightAmount = 0;

            if(enemy.getId()[0] == ID.EnemyL1){
                double a = (10 + defaultWeights.get(enemy)) / Math.pow((20 - 1), 2);
                weightAmount =  (a * Math.pow(player.getLevel() - 1, 2) + defaultWeights.get(enemy)) * difficulty; //a(x - h)^2 + k
            }

            int cWeight = (int) MathHelper.clamp(weight + (float) weightAmount, 1, 9999999);
            for(int i = 0; i < cWeight; i++){
                enemyWeights.addLast(en);
            }
        }
```

The above is for cycling through some enemies in a Hashtable and using a parabola to change the weights based on the current level, making it more challenging, below are the lists:

```
protected LinkedList<Class<? extends Enemy>> enemyWeights = new LinkedList<Class<? extends Enemy>>();
protected Hashtable<Class<? extends Enemy>, Integer> defaultWeights = new Hashtable<Class<? extends Enemy>, Integer>();
protected Hashtable<Class<? extends Enemy>, Integer> currentWeights = new Hashtable<Class<? extends Enemy>, Integer>();
```

EnemyWeights is the main list, defaultWeights is used to act as the shift horizontally for the parabola, and currentWeights is used to get the enemies currentWeights.

Comment: It looks like `enemy` is an instance of `Class`, otherwise this wouldn't even compile. Surely you want an *instance* of `Enemy`, at which point you can just cast it to `Enemy` if you need to... it would be much easier to help you if you'd show more code.

Comment: The code I used to define the enemy variable is as follows: `Class<? extends Enemy> enemy = e.nextElement();` For e is an enumeration cycling through a list of weighted enemies, should I just change `Class<? extends Enemy>` directly to `Enemy` instead?

Comment: That's getting the *class* of Enemy. Apparently it's not cycling through a list of enemies, but a list of *classes*... we'd still need more context, but in the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of class `java.lang.Class` is an object that contains information about what a specific class looks like. It's not an instance of the class that it describes. You have a `Class<Enemy>` object but that is not an `Enemy` object, so trying to cast it will cause a `ClassCastException`.

How you can solve this depends on the rest of the program which you didn't show, so it's hard to give you any useful answer to this. Make sure that `enemy` is an `Enemy` object instead of a `Class<Enemy>` object.

An analogy: You have a blueprint of a house (a plan that describes what a house looks like), and you're trying to treat that as if it is an actual house.

**edit** In these lines you are doing exactly what I described above:

```
Class<? extends Enemy> en = e.nextElement();
Enemy enemy = en.cast(Enemy.class);
```

You have a list of `Class<? extends Enemy>` (a list of `Class` objects that describe what different enemy classes look like) and then you try to treat each of them as if they are actual `Enemy` objects.

Comment: Oh, wow I just understood what you said! Thanks for the answer :)